# Cypress - How to validate a json object

Tags: cypress

I was checking out the open weather API and applying some cypress API testing methods to the JSON response. How do I validate a JSON object response like here:

```
JSON response (partial)...  {
 

"coord": {
   "lon": -0.13,
   "lat": 51.51
 },
```

This is the assert I tried:

```
expect(resp.body).to.have.property('coord','lon: -0.13, lat: 51.51')
```

> The assertion error states: .... expected { Object (coord, weather,
> ...) } to have property 'coord' of '{lon: -0.1257, lat: 51.5085}', but
> got { lon: -0.1257, lat: 51.5085 }

It appears to be a syntax issue with the apostrophe use or in how the assertion is constructed, but I am unsure what to do.  I tried diff. combos of braces and ' and ", but am unable to resolve it.

Comment: Hi @davilo61. You have to convert your object to a JSON string before assertion: `expect(JSON.stringify(resp.body)).to.contain('"coord": { "lon": -0.13, "lat": 51.51 }')`

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
cy.request('some_url')
  .its('body')
  .its('coord')
  .should('include', {
    lon: -0.13,
    lat: 51.51
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The above worked well!

Answer (score 0):

To make an assertion over the object's content, just do something like Alapan Das mentioned, or try something like this:

```
const res = {
            "coord": {
                "lon": -0.13,
                "lat": 51.51
            }
        }
expect(res.coord).to.have.property('lon', -0.13)
expect(res.coord).to.have.property('lat', 51.51)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I will try the above as well.